# Simple ISERROR Calculated Field Assistance

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a simple calculated field `=[Total Reviews Failed]/[Total Reviews Completed]`. The problem is that if these numerical columns are blank, The field returns `#DIV/0!`.

Can I replace the `#DIV/0!` with blanks instead using an **ISERROR** statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `If` operator ([see the docs for more details](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)).  The first parameter is your conditional, the second is the value to calculate if the conditional is true, the third parameter is the value to calculate if the conditional is false.

For example: `=If([Total Reviews Completed] > 0, [Total Reviews Failed]/[Total Reviews Completed], '')`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!